# How to format a float with a maximum number of decimal places and without extra zero padding?

Tags: python, string-formatting, padding

I need to do some decimal place formatting in python. Preferably, the floating point value should always show at least a starting 0 and one decimal place. Example:

```
Input: 0
Output: 0.0
```

Values with more decimal places should continue to show them, until it gets 4 out. So:

```
Input: 65.53
Output: 65.53

Input: 40.355435
Output: 40.3554
```

I know that I can use {0.4f} to get it to print out to four decimal places, but it will pad with unwanted 0s. Is there a formatting code to tell it to print out up to a certain number of decimals, but to leave them blank if there is no data? I believe C# accomplishes this with something like:

```
floatValue.ToString("0.0###")
```

Where the # symbols represent a place that can be left blank.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What you're asking for should be addressed by rounding methods like the built-in [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function.  Then let the `float` number be naturally displayed with its `string` representation.

```py
>>> round(65.53, 4)  # num decimal <= precision, do nothing
'65.53'
>>> round(40.355435, 4)  # num decimal > precision, round
'40.3554'
>>> round(0, 4)  # note: converts int to float
'0.0'
```

Comment: ..... Yeah. Yeah, that'd be it. I was looking for formatting because that's how the original code accomplished it, but this is what I want. Guess you could call that a brain-fart.

Comment: This does not work; `round(0.000000001, 4)` gives `0.0`

Comment: @user5359531 It does work. `0.0000` and `0.0` are equivalent. If you want a string, then you need to use something like format.

Answer (score 9):

Sorry, the best I can do:

```
' {:0.4f}'.format(1./2.).rstrip('0')
```

Corrected:

```
ff=1./2.
' {:0.4f}'.format(ff).rstrip('0')+'0'[0:(ff%1==0)]
```

Comment: You're most of the way there.  His C# example would format `1` as `'1.0'` and yours would format it as `'1.'`.

Comment: float('{:0.4f}'.format(x).rstrip('0')) this should take care of the issue with passing ints too. 
>>>float('{:0.4f}'.format(1).rstrip('0'))
1.0

Comment: @tapan:  That returns a float, not a string.

Answer (score 3):

From trial and error I think `:.15g` is what you want:

```
In: f"{3/4:.15g}"
Out: '0.75'

In f"{355/113:.15g}"
Out: '3.14159292035398'
```

(while `f"{3/4:.15f}" == '0.750000000000000'`)

Comment: Keep in mind that `g` specifier may switch to scientific notation for very large or small numbers. For example `f"{1/11300:.15g}"` results in `'8.84955752212389e-05'`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def pad(float, front = 0, end = 4):
    s = '%%%s.%sf' % (front, end) % float
    i = len(s)
    while i > 0 and s[i - 1] == '0':
        i-= 1
    if s[i - 1] == '.' and len(s) > i:
        i+= 1 # for 0.0
    return s[:i] + ' ' * (len(s) - i)

>>> pad(0, 3, 4)
'0.0   '
>>> pad(65.53, 3, 4)
'65.53  '
>>> pad(40.355435, 3, 4)
'40.3554'
```

Comment: You're most of the way there. His C# example would format `1.0` as `'1.0'` and yours would format it as `'1.'`.

Comment: Interesting solution. It works for whole numbers, but trying to pass in a value of say, 2.5 always seems to return `None`. I'll poke around a bit more. I was kind of hoping there was something built into the format function to handle this.

Comment: Oh sorry - i copied it from my pyshell and it looked good with tabs but it corrupted the identation.

Comment: Seems to be working now. I'll give this the answer unless somebody can come up with a solution I that suits me better.